# How do I restrict foreign keys choices in admin formset to related objects only in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

How do I limit choices of a ForeignKeyField of an InlineForm in Django Admin, depended on the selected object in the AdminForm.

The problem is that InlineForm does not know anything about the object from the related Admin Form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the parent object from the InlineAdmin to the FormSet to the actual Form. Took me quite a moment to figure that out.
In the example below `CalibrationCertificateData` is relate to the `CalibrationCertificate` and I only want to show `Quantities` that are related with the SensorCategory.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms import ModelForm, BaseInlineFormSet
from src.admin import site_wm
from . import models
from quantity_management.models import QuantitySensor

# Register your models here.
site_wm.register(models.CalibrationInstitute, site=site_wm)


class CertDataAdminForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.CalibrationCertificateData
        fields = "__all__"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Make sure that we only show the Quantites that are related to the selected Cert>Sensor>Category
        """
        self.parent_obj = None
        if 'parent_obj' in kwargs:
            self.parent_obj = kwargs['parent_obj']
            del kwargs['parent_obj']
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.parent_obj:
            # Do the actual filtering according to the parent object
            category_id = self.parent_obj.Sensor.Category_id
            self.fields['Quantity'].queryset = QuantitySensor.objects.filter(Sensor_id=category_id)


class CertDataAdminFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    form = CertDataAdminForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self, index):
        """
        Make sure the form knows about the parent object
        """
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(index)
        if hasattr(self, 'parent_obj') and self.parent_obj:
            kwargs['parent_obj'] = self.parent_obj
        return kwargs


class CalibrationDataAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = models.CalibrationCertificateData
    extra = 0
    form = CertDataAdminForm
    formset = CertDataAdminFormSet

    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        """
        give the formset the current object, so it can limit the selection choices according to it
        """
        formset = super().get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if formset is not None:
            formset.parent_obj = obj
        return formset

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        print(self.parent_model)
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)


@admin.register(models.CalibrationCertificate, site=site_wm)
class CalibrationCertificateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (
        CalibrationDataAdmin,
    )
```